# How to make bxslider adjust height to container div/browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, image-gallery, bxslider

I am trying to use bxslider to make a full-height slider that is dependent on the browser window, so the entire slide is always showing.

As it is now, it is adjusting its width based on the browser window, but I can't get it to adjust its height.

- Do I have to somehow adjust the image height itself (within the slide) to be based on the browser window?
- Is there another slider plugin I should be using for this?

Thanks in advance!